# Find ancestor in a List of family in Prolg

Tags: prolog

```
familija(father,mother,list_of_child).

familija(1,2,[9,10]).
familija(1,3,[11]).
familija(4,5,[12,13,14]).
familija(6,7,[8]).
familija(8,9,[15]).
familija(11,13,[16]).
```

this is database,I need to find list of ancestors of given X
    ?-ancestor(16,L).
    L=[12,13,1,3,4,5].

Comment: What did you try? What is not working with that attempt?

Comment: Furthermore, aren't the anchestors `[11, 13, 1, 3, 4, 5]`? `12` is an "aunt" or "uncle" of `16`.

Comment: I know how to work with one child but I don’t know how to start with list of children

Comment: Well then it might help to share the "one child" code, such that we can use this as a start to implement the list of anchestors. Hint: use `findall/3`.

Comment: ancestor(X,L):-familija(Y,Z,X),append([Y,Z],L).

Comment: But here your `ancestor/2` is only a *direct* parent of `X`, furthermore here `X` should be a *list* of children, not an individual child.

Comment: I don’t know how to implement it with a list of cildren

Comment: Hint: use `member/2`.

Answer (score 0):

Typically one does not wrap items in lists in a predicate if it makes sense to yield these individually, since then it becomes harder to make a "chain" of predicates to filter, or generate other values. So it is typically better to "emit" individual items in intermediate predicates.

A parent of a child can be obtained with:

```
parent(Parent, Child) :-
    (familija(Parent, _, Children); familija(_, Parent, Children)),
    member(Child, Children).
```

The nice thing is that this works *multidirectional*: we can query the individual children of a `Parent`, but we can also query what the parents are of a given `Child` (or check if a `Parent` is the parent of `Child`, or iterate over all parent-child relations).

For example:

```
?- parent(P, 16).
P = 11 ;
P = 13.
```

Now we can make a transitive closure over the `parent/2` predicate, to define an `ancestor/2`:

```
ancestor(X, Z) :-
    parent(X, Z).
ancestor(X, Z) :-
    parent(X, Y),
    ancestor(Y, Z).
```

So `X` is an ancestor of `Z`, given `X` is a parent of `Z`, or given `X` is a parent of `Y`, and `Y` is an ancestor of `Z`.

So now for a given child, we can query all the ancestors:

```
?- ancestor(X, 16).
X = 11 ;
X = 13 ;
X = 1 ;
X = 4 ;
X = 3 ;
X = 5 ;
false.
```

So now the only thing we need to do is wrap these in a list. We can do that with [**`findall/3`** [swi-doc]](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=findall/3):

```
ancestor_list(Decendant, Ancestors) :-
    findall(Ancestor, ancestor(Ancestor, Decendant), Ancestors).
```

This then gives us:

```
?- ancestor_list(16, L).
L = [11, 13, 1, 4, 3, 5].
```